# Is it necessary to add one extra column in hibernate one to many mapping while retrieving data from database?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

This is my employee table

```
+----+------------+-----------+--------+
| id | first_name | last_name | salary |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+
| 1  | Manoj      | Kumar     |   5000 |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+
```

This is my certificate table using one to many mapping

```
+----+------------------+-------------+
| id | certificate_name | employee_id |
+----+------------------+-------------+
| 1  | MBA              |          1  |
| 2  | PMP              |          1  |
| 3  | MCA              |          1  |
+----+------------------+-------------+
```

Now for retrieving data I can use `session.createCriteria(Employee.class);`

Do I need to add join column of `employee_id` in certificate entity class ?

Can I get `certificate_name` without adding column `employee_id` ? If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to add an extra column to the Certificate table, then your Employee entity should look something like:

```
   @Entity
    public class Employee {

       @Id
       @Column(name = "id")
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       private Long langId;

       @Column(name = "first_name")
       private String firstName;

       @Column(name = "last_name")
       private String lastName;

       @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
       @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "employee_id")
       private Set<Certificate> certificates;
```

Comment: do i need to add join column of employee_id  in certificate entity class ?

Comment: that's not what i asked .

Comment: Yes you do need a join column.

Comment: Thank you very much . edit your answer and write your last comment in that i will upvote then